# Code for searching the screen for specific word [PYTHON]

Tags: python

I made myself a little website that generates random names when you press a button on the screen.I wrote a part of code for automatic clicking on that button using the coordinates,but I want it to stop when the name 'BARKIN' comes out on the screen.(On my website the words are copy-pastable,not in an image form.)
I don't want to use urllib to find it,how can I do 'screen-reading' part of code without using urrlib ?

Here is the automatic clicker part of my code (n=10 is just for example to click it 10 times and I couldn't figure out the rest)

```
import pyautogui
n = 10
for i in range(0, n):
      pyautogui.click(x=730, y=320)
```

Any help is appreciated,thank you.

Comment: `pyautogui` sounds like a bit of a blunt instrument for doing what you want. `selenium` is a package that can be used for web applications GUI testing, and is also being used extensively for scraping. I know that what you want to do is really simple with `selenium`.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron thank you for your comment.I am not familiar with selenium,if I change the text form to an image (like .png) can it be done by pyautogui ?

Comment: I am not familiar with `pyautogui`, but I scanned its API, and it interacts with the screen at a *physical* level, so if your web-site's zoom changes, or the window moves, the coordinates for clicking and identifying text will change. In `selenium` you can access the displayed web page via the DOM (using **xpath** of **CSS**-like selectors), as well as read text from DOM elements.